# In MVC Edit Action {HTTP POST} Using UpdateModel vs Request.Form Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working through sample MVC Nerdinner tutorial and using it on the AdventureWorks database. I have created an Edit action in the CategoryController to edit Product Category in AdventureWorks. The only updateable field in this table is the Name (the other fields - ID, RowGUID and UpdateDate are autogenerated). So my edit form View has only 1 field for the Name (of Product Category). My "Save" action for the edit is below: -

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection){
        ProductCategory p = awRepository.GetProductCategory(id);
        try
        {
            //UpdateModel(p);
            p.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
            awRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = p.ProductCategoryID });
        }
        catch
        {
            foreach (var err in p.GetRuleViolations())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(err.PropertyName, err.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return View(p);
        }
    }
```

If I use the code as above, everything works as long as the Name I enter is valid (thus there is no exception). If I introduce an error (which is raised by GetRuleViolations if the Name is blank or for testing purposes is a particular "Test" string) I get a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on this line in the View (Category/Edit.aspx) when the Edit View is redrawn (to show the user the error and allow him to correct)

```
     <%= Html.TextBox("Name") %>
```

If I update my ProductCategory using UpdateModel(p) instead of using the Request.Form variable, everything works fine; Valid data is saved and invalid data redraws the view showing the error message.

My question is: what is the difference between UpdateModel and manual updating my variable by reading the values from Request.Form collection? The Nerdinner tutorial seems to suggest that both are equivalent. So I am surprised that one works smoothly and the other raises an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1396019/3006051.aspx

> So, for every error you add with
>   ModelState.AddModelError() and call
>   the View again, MVC Framework will try
>   to find an AttemptedValue for every
>   error it finds. Because you didn't add
>   them, MVC will throw an exception.
>
> Normally you don't need to add these
>   values: AttemptedValues are
>   automaticaly populated when you use
>   DefaultBinding (by calling
>   UpdateModel() or by passing the object
>   to bind as an Action Method paramter:
>   public ActionResult
>   Create(FormCollection Form,
>   YourObjectType yourObject).

Looks like the following is done automatically by UpdateModel, but not done manually by yourself?

```
if (Form["Name"].Trim().Length == 0)
{    
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is required");    

    //You missed off SetModelValue?
    ModelState.SetModelValue("Name", Form.ToValueProvider()["Name"]); 
}
```

Comment: Yep, when I was doing things that way, I had to set the Model value as well. I've since moved to using DataAnnotations to provide most of this logic on custom view models.